# Create a Form in a Block using API that sends captured data to email

Tags: 7, forms, blocks, rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send email of form data?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/43861/send-email-of-form-data)

So I have a simple three field form which I've created in HTML/CSS, see here:

[image: Simple email sign up form]

Now I want to put this into a block module, generate the form fields using Drupal Form API (is this appropriate or should I just stick with my existing HTML markup?). And on submission of the form I want it to email the details to a designated email. Is Drupal Triggers appropriate for this, if not, what is?

Any guidance on where to go with this would be amazing. Thanks so much for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create the form using [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module. This will also send an email to a chosen address. Unfortunately this will create just a normal page, not a block.

To show it in a block you'll need to create a view that renders the whole webform (which is a node) or to use mini panels with the same rendered node.

Answer (score 1):

Use [simple news module](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews) which will give you lots of e-newsletter features out of the box.

For new features you can extend above module to suit your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to this problem,

- You can use "webform " module and theme it using $form[theme], your start can be [here](http://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/themeing-drupal-7-forms-including-css-and-js)
- you can use [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) to create a custom form. Your good start is [FORM API Guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826)
- To trigger a Mail on submission, you can use rules OR triggers OR just a submit function