# Send email of form data?

Tags: 7, blocks, emails

I have a block module that looks like this:

[image]

Created in the following way:

```
function VL_newsletter_signup_block_info() {
  $blocks['my-block-id'] = array(
    'info' => t('Enjoy Stories? - Newsletter Signup'),
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_block_view().
 */
function VL_newsletter_signup_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'my-block-id':
      //$block['subject'] = t('Block Name');
      $block['content'] = VL_newsletter_signup_contents();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

/**
 * custom html block
 * @return string
 */
function VL_newsletter_signup_contents() {
  return '<div class="col4 stories nobile">
    <h2>Enjoy stories?</h2>
    <h3>Sign up to recieve regular news</h3>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="First name">
        <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Last name">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" >
        <input class="send" type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    </div>';
}
```

At the moment my form is static HTML as can be seen, but I plan to use Drupal Form API to render it. My question is: on pressing send, how can I email the form data to a designated admin email address. Can I use triggers somehow or is there another function in Drupal API that could achieve this?

Comment: Why not using Webforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [drupal_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) function to send the mail data. You can also use [HTML Mail](http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail) module to integrate nice email templates.

I have shown drupal_mail() function.

```
$params = array('current_conditions' => $data);
  $to = 'user@example.com';
  $message = drupal_mail('example', 'notice', $to, $language, $params, FALSE);
  // Only add to the spool if sending was not canceled.
  if ($message['send']) {
    example_spool_message($message);
  }
```

Comment: You'll also have to implement `hook_mail($key, &$message, $params)`: `function VL_newsletter_signup_mail($key, &$message, $params) { ... }` as per https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7